# QGIS 3.6 splitwithlines algorithm does not always split

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm trying to split one line layer with another line layer, and additionally get the vertices where they intersect.

However, if a line is self-intersecting, it does not split the underlying layer. In addition, some of the lines that are touching the underlying line, but not crossing them are not creating a split. Check the gist with the data to try it yourself.

I guess some floating point precision problem here, so I'm open for any advice on how to solve this issue.

As a workaround, I've tried extending the lines, but then I get two intersection vertices where the two lines meet on a baseline.

Check the sources here: https://gist.github.com/suricactus/9e43005bc1ca5f35d375bbde787a8a8e